# setState not changing how to setstate StatefulWidget to StatefulWidget?

Tags: dart, flutter

StatefulWidget to StatefulWidget
How to Change String TimeSetdata in class Test2 setstate

```
   class Test1 extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _Test1State createState() => _Test1State();
    }

    class _Test1State extends State<Test1> {
      String TimeSetdata = "9.00 AM";
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       ...
       Text(TimeSetdata);
      }
    }
    class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _Test2State createState() => _Test2State();
    }

    class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ...
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            TimeSetdata = "11.00 AM";
          });
        };
      }
    }
```

How to setState in Class Test2 Change String TimeSetdata in Widget Text(TimeSetdata) to "11.00 AM";

Comment: Where do you add `Test()` in `build()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow the parent to pass a callback function to the child and pass a callback, when called from the child, updates the value in the parent.

This assumes that `Test2` is a child of `Test1` (you didn't make this clear in your question)

```
typedef StringCallback = void Function(String);

class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
  Test2({@required this.onPressed});

  final StringCallback onPressed;

  @override
  _Test2State createState() => _Test2State(onPressed: onPressed);
}

class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
  _Test2State({@required this.onPressed});

  final StringCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    onPressed: () => onPressed(),
  }
}

class _Test1State extends State<Test1> {
  String TimeSetdata = "9.00 AM";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
   Test2(onPressed: (s) => setState(() => TimeSetdata = s),
   ...
   Text(TimeSetdata);
  }
}
```